# custom listview empty edittext and checkbox

Tags: android, checkbox, android-edittext, custom-adapter

I have a custom array adapter which has a imageview, 2 textviews an edittext and a checkbox. I need to get the text from my textviews and my edittext then send that data to another activitya textview when the checkbox is checked.

How can I set up a method to check if the edittext is empty as I need the checkbox only to trigger when there is a value in the edittext.

How can I get the data sent through to another activity.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take your `EditText` variable and call `getText()` on that variable to check if it is empty.

E.g.

```
if (myEditText.getText().toString() == "") {
     // trigger checkbox
}
```

To pass data from one activity to another you use intents. See here: [How do I pass data between Activities in Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android)